# Asp.Net Image.ImageUrl shared imageurl not working when hosted

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a legacy Asp.Net application which renders images from a shared n/w folder (UNC). This was working prior. We recently migrated this to cloud. When we ran this app locally, the image got loaded. When hosted in **IIS 8** , it does not.

```
imgmodal.ImageUrl = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImgPath"]).ToString() + item.Med_Image_Path;
```

For the shared location, permission was provided to everyone with **read, write and execute access**.

I tried accessing the file with browser and it worked as well.

Is there something else I am missing?

Raaj

Comment: 1- This question doesn't have anything to do with asp.net MVC. 2- You don't need brackets around `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImgPath"]`. 3- You didn't upload the images to the cloud? This obviously doesn't work.

Comment: When you say "we recently migrated this to cloud", does the cloud location have access to the UNC path? My guess is no.

Comment: @Eric King, Yes, we have uploaded the images to cloud shared folder location and it has access to the cloud server